# RUN FAILED in netbeans ( C++)

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, registry

On running the following C++ code to extract entire registry sub-keys of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, I am getting `RUN FAILED (exit value 1..)` error in netbeans. Only one sub-key is being opened i.e the `open()` function runs once.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) to `RegOpenKeyEx` function.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    #define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
    #define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383
    #define MAX_SUB_KEYS 10000
    using namespace std;
    void QueryKey(HKEY);
    void open(HKEY,string [],int);

    void open(HKEY hkey12,string subkey[],int m)
        {
        int u=0;
        while(u<m)
         { 
            HKEY hkey1;
            const char* sub=subkey[u].c_str();
       if( RegOpenKeyEx(hkey12,
            sub,
            0,
            KEY_READ,
            &hkey1) == ERROR_SUCCESS
          )
       {    
          QueryKey(hkey1);
       }
       else { cout<<"Subkey open failed "<<endl;}

       RegCloseKey(hkey1);
       u++; 
       }
     }

    int main()
    {
       HKEY hTestKey;

       if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            NULL,
            0,
            KEY_READ,
            &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS
          )
       {
          QueryKey(hTestKey);
       }

       RegCloseKey(hTestKey);
       return 0;  

    }

    void QueryKey(HKEY hKey)    // This function fetches the actual parameters. 
    {   
        TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
        DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
        TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name 
        DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
        DWORD    cSubKeys=0;               // number of subkeys 
        DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
        DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
        DWORD    cValues=0;            // number of values for key 
        DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
        DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
        DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
        FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

        DWORD i, retCode; 
        TCHAR achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME]; 
        DWORD valueData;   // BYTE valueData[2048]; // buffer for value data
        DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;  //pointer to size of value name
        DWORD valueType; // buffer for value type
        DWORD size=2049; // pointer to size of value data

        // Get the class name and the value count. 
        retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
            hKey,                    // key handle 
            achClass,                // buffer for class name 
            &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
            NULL,                    // reserved 
            &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
            &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
            &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
            &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
            &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
            &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
            &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
            &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

        string subkey[cSubKeys];
        string values[cValues];
        int typev[cValues];

        // Extract the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.
        if (cSubKeys)
        {

            for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
            { 
                cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
                retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i,
                         achKey, 
                         &cbName, 
                         NULL, 
                         NULL, 
                         NULL, 
                         &ftLastWriteTime); 
                if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
                {
                    subkey[i]=achKey;
                }
            }
        } 

        // Enumerate the key values. 
        if (cValues) 
        {  
            for (i=0, retCode=ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++) 
            { 
                cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

                achValue[0] = '\0'; 
                retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, 
                    achValue, 
                    &cchValue, 
                    NULL, 
                    &valueType,
                    (BYTE *)valueData,
                    &size);

                if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
                { 
                    values[i]=achValue;
                    typev[i]=valueType;
                } 
                else { cout<<"Error"<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
        int d=0;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sub Keys of "<<"are displayed below- "<<endl<<endl;
        while(d<cSubKeys){
            cout<<subkey[d]<<endl;
            d++;
        }

        d=0;
        cout<<endl;
        if(!values[0].empty())  {
        cout<<"Values are displayed below- "<<endl<<endl;
         while(d<cValues){
            cout<<values[d]<<"     "<<typev[d]<<endl;
            d++;
           }

    }
        open(hKey,subkey,cSubKeys);

    }
```

Comment: What did you learn about your code when you ran it in a debugger?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  
On running the debugger, it showed segmentation fault and I edited the code to resolve that. Its showing the subkeys now, but its not complete.